# Solving algebraic equation (compound interest)

Tags: functions

**Task:** Say you have an initial capital $c_0$ on your bank account and after each year the bank gives you $p \%$ of your hole capital $c$ what you directly put to your bank account. Additionally, you deposit another $t\$$ on your bank account at the end of each year after the bank paid you the interest. After how many years will your capital exceed $b$, i.e. when does $c > b$ hold?

**My recurrence formula approach:**
$$
f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R};\space\space f(x) = \begin{cases}(1+\dfrac{p}{100})\cdot c_0 + t, \space \text{if }\space x = 1\\[10pt](1+\dfrac{p}{100})\cdot f(x-1) + t, \space\text{else }\\\phantom{x}\end{cases}
$$

Where $f(x)$ describes $c$ after $x$ years.

**Solution:** I solved it using telescoping, since it is a rather simple recurrence relation:
$$
f(n) = p\cdot f(n-1) + t = p\cdot(p\cdot f(n-2) + t) + t = \ldots = p^n \cdot c_0 + \sum\limits_{k =0}^{n-1}p^k \cdot t \\= p^n \cdot c_0 + \dfrac{1-p^{n}}{1-p}\cdot t.
$$
Notice that for simplicity we define $p := \dfrac{\text{percentage}}{100} + 1$, in contrast to the $p$ we used above, which was the "raw" percentage.

Now I'm trying to solve for $n$, which doesn't seem that easy to me. Moreover, is there a function that better represents my problem? I just started diving into analysis a few days ago so my knowledge is very little. I'm thankful for any helpful comment!

Comment: What is $b$? Also your recurrence relation said $f(x) = (1+ \frac{p}{100}) f(x-1) + t$ but later on, you are taking only $p$.

Comment: @MathLover $b$ is a given constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$p^n \cdot c_0 + \dfrac{1-p^{n}}{1-p}\cdot t  \stackrel{(1)}{=} (k+1)^n \cdot c_0 + \dfrac{1-(k+1)^n}{k} =  (k+1)^n \cdot c_0 + \dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{(k+1)^n}{k} = \\[20pt](k+1)^n \cdot(c_0 -\dfrac{1}{k})+\dfrac{1}{k} = b  \Longleftrightarrow (k+1)^n = \dfrac{b}{c_0 -\dfrac{1}{k}} -\dfrac{1}{(c_0 -\dfrac{1}{k}) \cdot k} \Longleftrightarrow \\[30pt]n =\dfrac{\ln  \left(\dfrac{b}{c_0 -\dfrac{1}{k}} -\dfrac{1}{(c_0 -\dfrac{1}{k}) \cdot k} \right)}{\ln(k+1)}\\[20pt]\phantom{x}$

(1) Substitution: $k :=1-p $

Now one can back substitute.

Answer (score 1):

In your recurrence relation, your $p$ should rather be $1 + \frac{p}{100}$ by your notation (since a factor larger than one means that the capital accumulates interest). Let's write $i = \frac{p}{100}$. If you put these into $f(n)$, the accumulated value at time $n$, we get
$$
f(n) = (1+i)^n c_0 + \frac{(1+i)^n - 1}{i} t = (1+i)^n \left[ c_0 + \frac{1}{i} \right] - \frac{t}{i} . 
$$
Solving $f(n) = b$, we can make $n$ the subject and thus solve for $n$:
$$
(1+i)^n \left[ c_0 + \frac{1}{i} \right] - \frac{t}{i} = b .
$$
Rounding $n$ up to the nearest integer then gives you the first time period where the accumulated capital exceeds $b$.

EDIT: To solve for $n$, first make $n$ the subject by moving all the terms without $n$ to one side wher possible:
$$
(1+i)^n = \frac{b + \frac{t}{i}}{ c_0 + \frac{1}{i}} .
$$
Take logarithms (any base will do) to get
$$
n \log(1+i) = \log \left(  \frac{b + \frac{t}{i}}{ c_0 + \frac{1}{i}} \right)
$$
Thus, we have isolated $n$ and we can solve
$$
n = \log \left(  \frac{b + \frac{t}{i}}{ c_0 + \frac{1}{i}} \right) / \log(1+i) .
$$

Comment: This should still answer your question - can you solve for $n$ from what I have written?

Comment: you edited when I already was working on my solution, sorry. The problem was that I had a typing mistake in my formula an thus couldn't solve it...